# Usuário e senha SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, ubuntu, sqldeveloper

Durante a instalação do SQL developer 17.3.1 no ubuntu 16.04, o mesmo não perguntou usuário e senha. Nesse caso não consigo logar, existe algum usuário padrão ou algum jeito de configurar um usuário?

Comment: O Oracle foi instalado !?

Comment: Sim, instalou completamente, abre e tudo mais. O problema é que não consigo logar para realizar as consultas nem nada do tipo.

Comment: Tente system/manager e sys/change_on_install